# Storing random number of foreign keys and values in a single column [Relational Database Design]

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

I have an entity Product_Cluster which is defined as a collection of key-value pairs, where key is a product attribute and value could either be an attribute value or some wrapper entity.
Example definitions for a cluster of HardDisks:

```
Attributes: color | capacity | price
Values :    black | 1TB      | mass

Attributes: color | capacity | price
Values :    black | 1TB      | premium
```

Here values `black` and `1TB` are direct product attributes and values `mass` and `premium` are wrapper entities which are defined as follows:

```
attribute_id | wrapper_name | definition
price        | mass         | price > 500 and price < 1000
price        | premium      | price > 1000 and brand IN ("A","B","C","D")
```

As you can notice definition of a wrapper could be more complex like

```
(exp1 or exp2) and (exp3 or exp4)
```

The above cluster and wrapper definitions result in the following cluster predicates:

```
cluster 1: color="black" and capacity="1TB" and  price > 500 and price < 1000
cluster 2: color="black" and capacity="1TB" and  price > 1000 and brand IN ("A","B","C","D")
```

Both wrapper and product_cluster entities will be versioned. So I want to track for a particular product_cluster version what wrapper versions were used for definition.

I was thinking of storing wrapper and product_cluster entities as follows:

```
Product_Cluster_Entity
id | cluster_id| version | definition | predicate

Wrapper_Entity
id | attribute_id| wrapper_name | definition | version
```

Here, definition in Product_Cluster_Entity would be a JSON type (MySQL 5.7.18). I am thinking of storing the JSON as an array of objects where each object could have the following structure :-

```
attibute_id, value, is_wrapper
```

If `is_wrapper == 1` then value is foreign key to `wrapper_entity` table else it is direct product value.

I would like a few comments regarding the above solution. I couldn't identify any obvious drawbacks of the above solution (DB Design noob :P ) Can we improve this solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you want to use nested foreign key mapping . you can simply add more columns and accordingly add checks to it ? , may be I can be wrong ! can you add more details about versioning here , any e.g ?

Comment: I can't add more columns as the number of attribute_ids in product_cluster entity description is not consistent.

Comment: This question is too broad, with or without a bounty. If you want a review, add some *working* code and post it at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm looking for review of design and not codereview.

Comment: So even more off-topic at StackOverflow.

Comment: There is nothing Relational about this design.

Comment: Can you add more details about the queries you need to run, please?

Answer (score 2):

Those expressions you propose are just strings to MySQL.  No `FOREIGN KEYS` are possible, no lookups of values, etc.

You *could* fetch the string expressions into your application and somehow "evaluate" them in the client.  But only if you have already fetched all the possible variables and make sure the expression does not croak and bring down the client.

A database is a repository for data.  It has limited capabilities -- Relations, Aggregations, Sorting, etc.  But not arbitrary string parsing nor arbitrary expression evaluation.

JSON can provide you flexibility (non-relational) data structuring.  But nothing in the direction you are asking about.

Bottom Line:  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very wary of storing complex condition strings directly in your database and evaluating them.

This kind of system could cause serious problems with an inexperienced user, and putting protections/exception handling in place could quickly become a big mess.

If you need these customisable conditionals, I would clearly define each of them under a certain 'type' of conditional and control the evaluation of them with 'condition type' classes in your application.

In your examples I see you effectively have three types of conditional, exact matches (color, capacity), a range (price), and a whitelist (brand). These could be put together in a traditional relational database as follows:

*Condition* - instances of conditions that can be attached to attributes

```
id | type_id 
 1      1      
 2      2      
 3      3
```

*Condition Type* - types of condition available

```
id | title 
 1   equivalence
 2   range
 3   whitelist
```

*Equivalence Condition* - additional data for instances of equivalence conditions

```
condition_id | value
     1         black
```

*Range Condition* - additional data for instances of range conditions

```
condition_id | lower_bound | upper_bound
     2             500           1000
```

*Whitelist Condition* - additional data for instances of whitelist conditions

```
id | condition_id | value
 1        3           A
 2        3           B
 3        3           C
```

This approach will take considerable development, but we have used it with success in some of our projects. It constrains the user to clearly defined conditionals.

As these conditions are unlikely to need to be indexed by anything other than their id or type_id, you could potentially save some development time by throwing the type specific details (those in the Equivalence, Range and Whitelist Condition tables) into a JSON column in the Condition table:

```
id | type_id  | detail
 1      1       {"value":"black"}
 2      2       {"lower_bound":500, "upper_bound":1000}
 3      3       {"values":['A','B',"C"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, let me say that your question is very interesting for me, because I like mysql very much. It is a database backend for storing lots of data and is well suited for complex tasks. The only problem is that mysql is a little bit complex for explaining simple things like conditional sql statements. A better way is to use a more beginner friendly database like sqllite which is supported by the python interpreter. The question is not: how to program a SQL Statement, the question is: how to program a python script which has access to a database. Because the two other answers here are very good i leave the details unanswered and hope that you will have success with your product database.